# CAN on psoc4 mail box configured to basic

Tags: embedded, can-bus, psoc

I am using CAN on PSOC 4 and I have a receive buffer mailbox configured to basic how can  read length of the message send to that mailbox or how can distinguish between if a data byte is empty or has a value of zero

I tried to read the message but if the data byte is empty it shows zero

Comment: It's helpful if you post the code, even if it's not working. Including the CAN setup.